# Align div's horizontally

Tags: css, wordpress, html, header

Trying to get this to work with my site, looked at some people who have had this problem also, but for some reason i can't get it to work. Is this code correct? should i start looking somewhere else to find the problem, cause when i put it in an actual table it works.

got it to work by doing this =

```
    .headerout
{    
  width 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerin
{    
  display: inline-block;
}
```

not tell these div's to align horizontally ?

```
<div class="headerout">
<div class="headerin"><div class="phone" style="white-space: nowrap;"> Call Toll Free: 888-674-4044</div>
    <div class="phone" ><img src="http://www.mphclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/quote.png" width="40" height="23"></div>
   <div class="phone" ><img src="http://www.mphclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/reservation1.png" width="40" height="23"></div>
</div></div>
```

Not pretty but does the trick for me.

Comment: `<font>` tags are deprecated, not a good idea to use them.

Comment: You have defined phone as a class in the CSS but given it an ID in the HTML.

Comment: JG, please read the pages [About] and [FAQ], you can't replace the original Question with "thanks".

Answer (score 1):

The image in the second div has a width set to 100% , so that div gets a 100% width, therefore there's no place for the other div on the same line...

But anyway your HTML has many problems : you're not suppose to put styles like that, you shouldn't use font tags, etc...

Comment: took your advice with the width, and got rid of font tags, still not working.

Comment: add a float:left; to your "row" class

Answer (score 0):

The CSS doesn't really make sense. *margin: 0 auto;* centers an element horizontally inside another element, it doesn't center its children if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Besides - your code is really bad. Don't use inline style, font tags and align parameters.

Comment: took your advice and got rid of inline, font tags, and align parameters,and margin:0... still not working.

Comment: You still have your main problem - wrong use of *margin: 0 auto*. You should set it to an element inside a container to center it horizontally. It won't do what you want if you set it on the parent element/container.